# Leading zeros in hex values

Tags: assembly, 8051

Reading over some assembly for a 8051 project and I'm having difficulty understanding why some hex values have leading zeros and some don't, am I right in presuming both examples set acc.5 to 1?

mov a, #020h

mov a, #20h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I right in presuming both examples set acc.5 to 1?

Yes.

---

But your hidden question is: "**Why have hex values a leading zero even if it seems not to be necessary?**"

Well, that's just for visual consistency with values beginning with 'A' to 'F'. If those would not start with a digit they would not be recognized as numbers but as identifiers.

```
    mov a, #0E0H  ; loads hex E0 (= dec 224) into ACC
    mov a, #E0H   ; loads the value of "E0H" into ACC, with any value defined as "E0H"
```

The author likes to write all values the same way. If there's a value without zero it might be a typo, a missed case, from another author, or for any other reason.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a bad style rule for trailing-h hex constants.  It makes it easier for someone to come along later and edit the `2` into an `F` or whatever without stopping to think about that syntax rule.  This is why I like `0x...` instead of trailing-h.  (Some assemblers do support both so you actually have a choice.)