# Z80 load immediate instruction

Tags: assembly, z80

I'm curently starting to learn Z80 assembly language and
I have the following snipet of code :

```
LD A, 53H
LD B, F5H
ADD A, B
halt
```

It simply loads two immediates into the registers A and B, and adds them up.

The problem I have is with the sencond line containing `LD B, F5H`.
The assembler is complaining about `undefined variable: F5H Line: 2`  with one assembler and `Invalid argument of the instruction` using a different assembler.

Can someone explain what syntax error I'm doing here?
the first line compiles with no errors.

Strangely, using the interactive assembly writer, doing `LD B, 0F5H` seems to fix the error, whereas in the first line, writing either `LD B, F5H` or`LD B, 0F5H` is fine, and both generate the same object code.

From the Z80 manual :

> Upon the execution of an LD E, A5h instruction, Register E contains A5h.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `F` is a letter, the assembler thinks `F5H` a symbol. Numbers should begin with a digit, no matter the base, to avoid confusion. That is why `0F5H` works. Note this depends on assembler.

Comment: I really had a dumb moment thinking about how ```B``` register is coded as ```b'000```and confusing it with a ```halt``` insruction which is ```b'0000``` on this platform or something like that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The documentation was misleading as well.

Comment: Same reason as in all assemblers that use trailing-h to indicate hex (instead of a leading `$` or `0x`), like Jester said, so basically a duplicate of [Leading zeros in hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58061348) and [How do I write letter-initiated hexadecimal numbers in masm code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33276232)

Comment: @PeterCordes I disagree on it being a duplicate but the linked question is indeed helpful. Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's not an *exact* duplicate, but the answer there answers this question.  Basics like this don't really need separate answers for each circumstance in which confusion happened, so my threshold for how close a question has to be is lower than for trickier concepts.